# Windows task scheduler not running full batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, taskscheduler

```
echo off
curl ..... C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\automate\ex.zip
jar xf C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\automate\ex.zip
Rscript C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\automate\test.R
```

I have the above batch file. The first step is to retrieve a zip file. The second step unzips it. The third step runs an independent R script.

The strange thing is that all steps execute successfully when running the batch file by double-clicking. However, when using the task scheduler, only the 1st and 3rd are executed. The 2nd line does not execute.

Any thoughts as to why this may be the case? How can I troubleshoot it?

Comment: Maybe the user who runs the scheduled task has no permissions to the folders you expect? You could begin by adding logging to redirect output to a file and see the exact error message.

Comment: @Alejandro thanks! How should I go about adding logging to a separate file?

Comment: How is the task configured to run?  As a test, I would specify the full path to all programs and files it is using.

Comment: Just redirect output of each invidual command to a file (otherwise the output remains in the console, which you can't see). Use something like `curl .......... >> c:\test\output.txt` or something like that. Then examine that file.

Comment: @Squashman I changed the "Start In" folder to the one where my files were located and it worked. Thanks!